# Android using lots of memory drawing a circle in a custom view

Tags: android

I have a custom view I've created that draws a circle, places a single text character in the middle, and sets the font to a custom icon font.  It looks like this

[image]

The code for it looks like this

```
public class IconView extends TextView
{
public static final String ICON_PROJECTOR = "A";
public static final String ICON_BLURAY = "F";
public static final String ICON_TUNER = "H";
public static final String ICON_CALL = "W";
public static final String ICON_HANG_UP = "X";
public static final String ICON_SLIDERS = "l";
public static final String ICON_KEYPAD = "t";
public static final String ICON_UP = "!";
public static final String ICON_DOWN = "@";
public static final String ICON_LEFT = "#";
public static final String ICON_RIGHT = "$";
public static final String ICON_UP_ALT = "%";
public static final String ICON_DOWN_ALT = "^";
public static final String ICON_LEFT_ALT = "&";
public static final String ICON_RIGHT_ALT = "*";
public static final String ICON_MENU_BACK = "<";
public static final String ICON_MENU_FWD = ">";

private int bgColor;

public IconView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    Typeface iconTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/hav.ttf");
    this.setTypeface(iconTypeface);
}

public void setIcon(String icon)
{
    this.setText(icon);
}

public void setColor(int color)
{
    bgColor=color;
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    int size = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size,size));
    this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    //Draw Background
    Rect rect = canvas.getClipBounds();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(bgColor);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawCircle(rect.centerX(), rect.centerY(), rect.width() / 2, paint);

    //Set Text Color
    this.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

It runs and looks beautiful.  Unfortunately, when it's running the entire application lags and my memory usage looks like this [image: memory].  I'm pretty sure that means something's leaking, and since I'm very new to this I don't know what in my onDraw method is causing it.  If I comment out everything in onDraw but super() then I get just the icon with the font, no circle, and the memory problems go away entirely.  I get a nice solid even line for memory and the app is snappy and responsive.

So what's wrong with my circle code, how can I fix it, or what should I replace it with?

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it!

Comment: I just dug around a bit in the source of `TextView.java` and `View.java` and it looks like the `setLayoutParam` method requests a re-layout of the text view. I guess this is probably not the effect you want to have in the draw method. I believe that may cause something like an "infinite loop" where your `onDraw` method triggers the layouting routine, which in turn causes the `onDraw` method to be called again during the next UI update step. You could validate that by adding some log output to the onDraw method or by setting a break point.

Comment: I went much simpler than you suggested: I started by commenting out the setLayoutParams line.  I'm not sure what that line was supposed to do (I copied the entire "draw a circle" thing from somewhere else on stackoverflow) but it doesn't seem to have been necessary.  Deleting both the size integer and the setLayoutParams method call seem to have fixed my memory problems without ruining my graphics.

Thanks!  If you want to repost as an answer I'll mark it as correct.